# Capture div element inside fancybox iFrame

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, iframe, fancybox

I am using google APIs to update file in G Drive and it is working absolutely fine. I am using fancybox iframe to edit documents, which are available on G Drive, and have "Done" button, as you can see in the attachment. What i want is to disabled button until document changes made in gdrive file editor saved to G Drive. When we edit the document there is a element which changed the text Saving... and then display **Saved to Drive**. I want to capture that element

Till now i have tried following code

```
1. console.log($("#"+iframeid).contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('body'));

2. console.log($("#"+iframeid).children().find('.goog-contorl'));

3. console.log($("#"+iframeid).contents().find(".goog-control"));



4. var iframe = document.getElementsByClassName("goog-control");
            console.log(iframe);
            var elmnt = iframe.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0];
            console.log(elmnt);
    
 5.   var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
            const ele =$(iframe).contents().find("html").html();
    
            console.log(ele);
```

And many more ways and all leads to one thing. Element is undefined.

Comment: Not familiar with fancybox but, If the iframe is not of "same origin", You can't see it's contents from the parent

Comment: SO there is no way to get that element?

Comment: **IF** the frames are not of **same origin**, **JavaScript access from parent** in a respectable browser is not possible. See [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). If however, you control both frames, you may be able to get access via `window.postMessage`

Comment: I have tried that also. As the data is coming from G Drive, i can't control that window. Is there any other alternative??

Comment: *have "Done" button, as you can see in the attachment.* Your question doesn't provide *attachment*. So it's a bit unclear. You can also try google-drive-api and see if that helps. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-drive-api/info) for "External API"

Comment: ok i'll try that also..Thanks for your help